# Bouncy Castle example for encoding CDR

Tags: encoding, bouncycastle, asn.1, cdr

I am trying to encode `PGWRecord CDR` using `ASN.1` notation, starting on page 89 in [this 3GPP TS Document](http://%20http://www.qtc.jp/3GPP/Specs/32298-850.pdf)

I've been looking for awhile for examples how I can do this, but to no avail. Are there any examples that can show me how to do this using `Bouncy Castle`? Or is there a better alternative than `Bouncy Castle` to encode this CDR?

Step by step instructions on how I can do this would be very nice!

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks all!

Answer (score 3):

Ya, just two months back i have worked on Bouncy castle to decode CDRS which of 3GPP stranded encoded file. Currently i am good in decoding and if any issues on decoding i can give more example and i can solve it easily solve it.

But for your question i can suggest some points and if you have any question pleas add comment. It not only help for you it can help for new bees who start with encode / decode process.

a) You did right API choice (Bouncy Castle) for encoding CDRS files

b) You can go for paid version of encode / decode APIs but it is too expansive

c) I have found 3 paid APIs which gives good and expected results, those are

```
1) [OSS Nokalva][1]
2) Obj-Sys
3) unigone
```

d) For me Bouncy castle gave 100% result then paid APIs even though they work well and good. If you want to use Bouncy castle then you need to put some more effort to work on encoding, So Bouncy castle is an API which support basic and some advanced parser, to do any encoding / decoding you need to write the java classes as per your ASN.1 syntax specification and so on.. I can write the steps but it will be too long so end of this answer i am giving you a link which explain it better. click on [this link](https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) and download `bcprov-jdk15on-154.tar.gz` file.

e) Unzip the package you downloaded and go to `bcprov-jdk15on-154\bcprov-jdk15on-154\src\org\bouncycastle\asn1\test` you will find N number of examples to encode/decode CDRs according to the ASN.1 syntax specification

f) If you want to understand with very simple example then go through [this link](http://www.bitpapers.com/2012/04/bouncy-castle-asn1-api.html) you can easily do your job

Still if you find difficult to understand then write a comment i will try to help my best.

Comment: would you be willing to provide an updated link? the content at the provided link is unavailable. thank you.

Comment: @sweetjonnie sorry to say this, it's bean 3 years I don't have working link. If you are intended to use `Bouncy Castle` you should  go through the samples they have provided or If you are okay with the payed API's then as per my opinion  `http://www.oss.com/asn1/products/asn1-java/asn1-java.html` is the best

Comment: @sweetjonnie I will try looking for working link, If I get one I will post hear

Comment: Please try if this link helps you `https://github.com/jporras66/hpms/tree/master/hpms-client/src/example/java/com/indarsoft/hps/examples/asn1`

Answer (score 1):

Try to look at [BinaryNotes](http://bnotes.sourceforge.net/). You have ASN.1 definition of what you are trying to encode. BinaryNotes will generate classes for encoding/decoding objects to/from ASN.1.

BinaryNotes works with xlst transformations to generate classes. You could modify the transformations in a way that it will use bouncy classes form encoding/decoding.

Comment: N.b., BinaryNotes hasn't been updated since at least 2011, and it appears not since 2007. Some changes have been made since then (there is a 2008 release of the ASN.1 specification documents, for example). It may be possible to use a freely-available compiler to generate Java classes or C/C++ code for use with JNI, e.g., Lev Walkin's: http://lionet.info/asn1c/compiler.html.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the encoding of `GPRSRecord` CHOICE would be something like that below.Be careful to tag values and conversion from string view to hex and BCD packing for `IMSI` and `GSNAddress` value :

```
ASN1EncodableVector v = new ASN1EncodableVector();

v.add(new BERTaggedObject(true, 0, new ASN1Integer(18))); //e.g. sgsnPDPRecord (18)
v.add(new BERTaggedObject(true, 3, new BEROctetString(Hex.decode("490154203237518")); //IMSI. String to BCD bytes conversion needed
v.add(new BERTaggedObject(true, 4, new BERTaggedObject(true, 0, new DEROctetString(Hex.decode("994507776655"))))); // GSNAddress
v.add(new BERTaggedObject(true, 5, new BEROctetString(Hex.decode("00DB")))); //ChargingID

byte[] encoded =  BERTaggedObject.getInstance(new BERTaggedObject(true, 78, new BERSet(v))).getEncoded(); //SGWRecord
```